# How to uninstall/remove plugin with pathogen for Vim

Tags: vim, pathogen

How do I uninstall a plugin I installed with pathogen?

Comment: Pathogen is not able to install anything, it just manages your runtimepath.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Locate your bundle folder which should be in:

Linux/Mac:  `~/.vim/bundle`

Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\(UserName)\vimfiles\bundle`

Windows7:   `C:\Users\(UserName)\vimfiles\bundle`

Delete the folder of the plugin you want to delete.

Note: If you chose a different directory for pathogen to install your plugin then locate that folder and delete the plugin folder accordingly.

Restart Vim

Tip: In Vim type `:echo $HOME` to see your Vim home directory

Answer (score 9):

Pathogen installs plugins as git submodules. Therefore uninstalling a plugin is removing a git submodule. Taking 'vim-rvm' as example plugin.

```
git submodule deinit bundle/vim-rvm
git rm bundle/vim-rvm
git rm --cached bundle/vim-rvm
rm -rf .git/modules/bundle/vim-rvm
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Although, I don't think step #3 (`git rm --cached`) is necessary is it?

Answer (score -4):

Do the reverse of what you did to install it.

Comment: Execute a vimball by typing its name backwards, with your back to the keyboard? ;-)